# Need VF Page Opportunity fields to hide/show when checkbox is checked

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, custom-controller, rendered

I have Vf page on Opportunity with custom controller. I need to make fields visible only after checkbox is checked. here is my code . something is missing . i'm getting fields hide all time.

**Vf Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="opportunityOrderDetail">
  <apex:form >
      <apex:pagemessages /> 
    <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity details">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportnuity Infromation" >
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.OwnerId }"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.Amount }"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.IsPrivate }"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.CloseDate }"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.Name }"/>    
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.NextStep}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.Account.Name }"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.StageName }"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.Type }"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.Probability }"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.LeadSource }"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.CampaignId}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.Status__c }"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.Primary_Customer_Email_Id__c}"/>
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.Primary_Competitor__c }"/>



    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Additional Information" >
        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Opportunity.Order_Details__c}" onchange="{!click}"  />
         <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="thePanel" action="{!click}"/> 
          <apex:pageBlockSection title="Order Details" id="OrderDetails" rendered="{!displayInputputText}">           
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.OrderNumber__c }" /> 
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.MainCompetitors__c }"/> 
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.CurrentGenerators__c }" />
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.DeliveryInstallationStatus__c }" />
        <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.TrackingNumber__c }" /> 
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

     <apex:pageBlockSection title="Description Information" >
         <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.Description }"/> <br/>
         <apex:inputField value="{! Opportunity.Reason_for_Rejection__c}"/> 

         </apex:pageBlockSection>




        <apex:pageBlockButtons >

        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save & New"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="cancel"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>


  </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

---

Here is My Custom Controller

```
 public class opportunityOrderDetail {
    public Opportunity oppty{get;set;}

     public Boolean displayInputputText{get;set;}

    public  opportunityOrderDetail(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        oppty=(Opportunity)controller.getRecord();}


    public PageReference click(){    
         if(oppty.Order_Details__c==true){
             displayInputputText = true;
         }
         else{
             displayInputputText = false;
         }
         return null;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rendering fields on click of checkbox is always a tedious job. Here is a small example were I rendered one `inputtext` when user checks the checkbox.

**VF page**:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="panel1">
    Check to show textbox:
    <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!check}" >

        <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" rerender="panel2" />
    </apex:inputCheckbox>
</apex:outputPanel>
<br/>
<apex:outputPanel id="panel2" >
    <apex:inputtext label="Enter value" value="{!checkText}" rendered="{!check}"/>

</apex:outputPanel><br/>
```

**Controller**:

```
public boolean check{get;set;}
public string checkText{get;set;}
```

If you want to populate any data into those fields then you can add `action` attribute to `actionSupport`.